# Apart from birds/wildlife and sports what are some "artistic" uses for telephoto lenses?

Tags: lens, telephoto, artistic

I mean no offence to birders and sports shooters, but I don't practice those types of photography.

So what other types/styles of shooting can be done with long (200-300mm+) lenses, other than the obvious?

Please provide example photos to better illustrate your point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pigeon-holing lenses is not always a worthwhile exercise. Any lens can work in virtually any setting.

Long lenses can be excellent in landscape situations, for example picking out and isolating a particular feature. The long focal length also has the effect of compressing perspective. They can also be used in street photography, where the length allows you to discreetly capture scenes.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My intention is to do the opposite, since I feel that long lenses are already pigeon-holed. Do you have any examples that might illustrate the points you have made?

Comment: http://www.lightharmony.com/blog/landscape-photograpy-with-telephoto-lenses-31.html

Comment: As Ansel Adams put it (I believe it was in *The Camera*), all photography is abstraction. While shallow DoF was never a big tool in his repertoire (f/64 works a lot better on view cameras than on, say, APS-C) he did tend to use long-focus lenses to excerpt interesting graphical elements of a scene. Whatever else a long/tele lens might do, its primary function is cropping the scene before us; everything else is perspective.

Answer (score 4):

My favorite use of telephoto in landscape photography is **compressing the scene**.  Matt explained this very nicely [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21812/how-can-a-telephoto-lens-take-great-landscape-photos).

Actually, I really like landscape without the sky and using compression with a telephoto.
[Excellent examples of this here](http://500px.com/photo/2223708) (photographs by Krzysztof Browko)

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common uses for a high focal length telephoto lens is to provide a very selective field of focus. Telephoto lenses, when focused on a subject in the foreground, much of the background will be extremely out of focus, providing a sort of artistic effect. This is amplified with a small f-number.

Answer (score 0):

[Zoom Burst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoom_burst) can give some interesting results.